# How to return a file URL from a Cordova Android Plugin

Tags: java, android, file, cordova, url

I have a hybrid Cordova Android app which uses one custom (i.e written by me) plugin. Amongst other things I use the plugin to grab file resources from external sources.  The relevantt Java code in the plugin is shown below

```
public static String grabFile(String url,String fName)
{
 File file = new File(filePath,fName);
 if ((null != file) && file.exists()) return file.toURI().toString();

 URL aurl;
 try{aurl = new URL(url);}catch(Exception e){return "";}  

 try(InputStream fIn = aurl.openStream();FileOutputStream fOut = new 
  FileOutputStream(file))
 {
  try
  {   
   byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
   int length;

   while ((length = fIn.read(buffer)) != -1) {fOut.write(buffer,0,length);}
   return file.toURI().toString();
  } 
  finally
  {
   fIn.close();
   fOut.close();   
  }
 }   
 catch(Exception e)
 {
  Feedback.postBackInfo(e.getMessage() + "grab file");
  return "";
 }
}
```

where `filePath`, `Feedback.postBackInfo` etc come from elsewhere in the plugin code. This typically returns something like this

```
file:/data/user/0/com.example.myapp/files/filename.png'
```

which I then use in front end (Webview) Javascript to assign image source and HTML element backgrounds

```
img.src = file:/data/user/0/com.example.myapp/files/filename.png
```

OR

```
element.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + 
file:/data/user/0/com.example.myapp/files/filename.png' + ')';
```

However, this does not work.  Clearly, the URL that I need to provide here is structured differently.  Just how should it be constructed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had considered deleting this question but decided to leave it here with code for the benefit of others.  The simple answer is `file:/data/user...` needs to be changed to `file:///data/user...`.  Just why the returned URI has a different format I cannot tell.